# WordPress domain configuration on a different server

Tags: domain, hosting

I have a webpage hosted in 'www.example.com' (for example) and a domain 'www.domain.com'. My problem is that I do not know how to point configure WordPress and make my page available online.

I've already tried changing the site address (www.domain.com) and the WordPress address (www.example.com) in General Settings and also from `wp-config.php`. I've also tried setting up apache virtualhost in apache2/sites-available but still nothing is working.

Any clue what do I need to do to get my website public?

Thank you

Comment: Can you please clarify which domain you would like your WordPress site to use? Is it correct you would like your site available via both `www.example.com` and `www.domain.com`?

Comment: Www.example.com is my hosting server and the domain name is www.domain.com. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Directing a new domain to a site the following components be configured:

1. The DNS records for your domain are configured with the IP address of your hosting provider. A records are the critical records and are usually used in combination with CNAME records. Your hosting provider's documentation the correct IP addresses to use, and your domain registrar's documentation for updating DNS records.
2. Your web server must be configured to receive requests from your domain. Most hosting providers use Plesk or cPanel both of which provide options to add new domains to your server with having to create `VirtualHost` entries manually. Search your hosting providers documentation for adding new domains to your account.
3. The WordPress codebase must be located in the directory created by the step above.
4. A database and a database user has been created for your WordPress site and the `wp-config.php` file updated with these database connection credentials. This is usually done via PHPMyAdmin or other tools provided by your hosting provider. If you have an existing WordPress database you can use PHPMyAdmin to import it.
5. Visit your domain in your browser to run the WordPress install if it's a new site, or view the existing site.

[Getting started with WordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Getting_Started_with_WordPress) provides a wealth of information on these topics.

If you have the above in place and still receive errors you will need to post more information about your specific setup and the errors you're receiving.

[WhoIs Lookup](https://whois.icann.org/en) is a good tool for finding information about your domain registrar. [What's my DNS](https://www.whatsmydns.net/) is a good tool for viewing your current DNS records.

Comment: That was my problem and your solution definitely worked! I tried to vote you but unfortunately I still do not have enough reputation to do so.
Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Glad to hear this info helped. I appreciate you wanting to upvote, but marking my answer as the accepted answer is enough.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just planning to change the domain names while remaining on the same server then all you've to do is to run this query over your WP DB .. Make sure your old url and new url doesn't have trailing slashes and always take backup of your DB before making any change!

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://www.oldurl', 'http://www.newurl') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';
UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://www.oldurl','http://www.newurl');
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://www.oldurl', 'http://www.newurl');
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value,'http://www.oldurl','http://www.newurl');
```

Comment: Still nothing. When I type http://www.newurl it doesn't return anything.
Should I need some configuration in apache or whatever?

Comment: Please explain in detail what server configuration are you using right now!